# Tool to generate an HTML page including all CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to know if a tool existed to generate a one HTML file from a set of HTML, CSS and Javascript files. It should parse the HTML and replace any include with the contents of the file.

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>My example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <script src="test.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="test" type="button" value='Test' onclick="testThat()"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Should output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>My example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
    .test {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function testThat() {
        alert('itWorks');
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="test" type="button" value='Test' onclick="testThat()"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

I am sure such a tool exists but I can't find it yet!

It should run on Windows, and being free is better (with a donation button if you liked the tool).

Comment: This sounds like a task to be automated. Is a command line tool ok?

Comment: So you need a tool that will (recursively) parse an HTML file, find file references, and include those files (and anything they contain) in your one file?  What's the  use case?

Comment: The use case is : https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/html-macro-38273085.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few such projects:

- [jasonbellamy/asset-inliner: Parses your markup and replaces the references to external assets with inline code](https://github.com/jasonbellamy/asset-inliner)
- [cburgmer/inlineresources: Inlines style sheets, images, fonts and scripts in HTML documents.](https://github.com/cburgmer/inlineresources)
- [cdata/collapsify: Collapsify inlines all the resources of a page into a single document](https://github.com/cdata/collapsify)
- [callumlocke/resource-embedder: Embeds the contents of external scripts and stylesheets into HTML.](https://github.com/callumlocke/resource-embedder)